# Как узнать, что твой адаптивный сайт показывается одинаково на всех экранах?

Tags: responsive, веб-программирование, ui

Как вы сами строите такие сайты? Чем проверяете?

Дело в том, что сервисы типа Dimensions, Screenfly показывают неправильно. Я поставил там экран 15", все исправил. Но потом когда зашел через 15" комп, там криво было то, что на сервисе выдавался правильно. Что посоветуете?

Comment: а что такое "сервисы" в Вашем понимании?

Comment: Все то, что выдает гуго при запросе "responsive site test"

Comment: те веб дизайнеры, которых я знаю, специально держат в виртуальных машинах типичные комбинации ОС+браузер. Плюс конечно же пару планшетов и телефонов. А также много знаний.

Comment: Много Знаний приходит с опытом

Comment: @KoVadim, ну, в противовес виртуалкам есть такие сервисы: http://browsershots.org/

Comment: @Fike я не понял что это. Ведь мне не кроссбраузерность нужно. Мне разрешения нужны

Comment: @navi1893 во-первых я не про разрешения, во-вторых они там внизу есть, хоть и не в самом лучшем варианте )

Comment: @navi1893, используйте [VirtualBox][1], это единственное решение, которое может гарантировать соответствие результатов теста объективной реальности.


  [1]: https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: а окошко браузера уменьшить до 15' дюймов не вариант ?
В ФФ вроде даже плугин для этих целей был

Comment: @navi1893, Изменить разрешение виртуального монитора эмулируемой машины из системы, на соответствующее интересующей вас диагонали. Или сделать несколько виртуальных машин, сконфигурировав драйвер в каждой под одну из интересующих диагоналей. Сложно, но надёжно как топор.

Comment: guest utils поставьте, в меню сверху поищите что-то типа "установить дополнения гостевой os"